# Console is not showing some elements on document.getElementsByTagName("Button");

Tags: javascript, html

I want to get all the HTML Button elements in the console **after clicking on an extension which of course changes the HTML code and adds new Buttons.**

I am using `document.getElementsByTagName("Button");`

Clicking on an extension changes the HTML code which adds more buttons to the HTML code but I don't see and change on running : `document.getElementsByTagName("Button");` in console** but after I right click on the new element and click on `inpect` (right click has to be on the new element or it doesn't show the new added html button elements) then it shows the new elements too.

**What is happening here?**

Let me show you some images:

1: [Normal Webpage before clicking on extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4HcQ70.png)

2: [After clicking on extension new elements added but no change in console result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpI7M0.png)

3: [After right click on new buttons and clicking on inspect the console result changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3M1qJ0.png)

Some help will be really appreciated.

Comment: would you share any details please? code, pictures, etc

Comment: @leftclick Added some images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the buttons show in the console in the last view and the previous views are *different*. There aren’t *extra*, it is a completely different set. You can tell because the console shows completely different IDs and class names in the summary.

You are searching the *document* for button elements.

There are two documents on screen. The one in the main viewport and the one in the iframe generated by the extension.

The set of buttons you see depends on which document you are inspecting.

Comment: That makes sense, then how do I get the elements from the iframe?

Comment: [HTML code of iframe](https://imgur.com/a/ZbsLzti), How do I get elements from this iframe?

Comment: I googled it but stuck at some problem of the same cross-origin policy or something.
Is there any workaround for it?

Comment: In most cases: No.

Answer (score -1):

document.getElementsByTagName("Button") returns an array with all found button elements

try

```
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
console.log(buttons[0]);
```

it logs the first found button, loop through the array to log them all

Comment: This will just log the first element in the resultant array, that is not the problem.
The problem is extension changed the HTML code and added new buttons but the resultant array is not changing until I inspect the element.

Comment: they are added after the log command, put the log command after the click if you can influence it

Answer (score -1):

YOU CAN TRY THIS

```js
buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");

for (button of buttons) {
  console.log(button)
}
```

```html
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
```

Comment: This is just a loop in the resultant array, that is not the problem.
The problem is extension changed the HTML code and added new buttons but the resultant array is not changing until I inspect the element.